# Hash conflict with ng-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, bootstrap-tabs

I am using `ng-router` and also Bootstrap tabs which are by default mapped with div IDs. Angular is treating tab links as routes and attempts to route them instead of opening up tabs? How do i tell angular that these links should be ignored or how do i implement tabs so that i don't have to use IDs? I have many such Bootstrap widgets such as tabs, panels which use IDs.

Angular links are like:

```
#/lesson/223
```

and tabs links are like:

```
#collapsablePanel
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap adapted to Angular (e.g. [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)) or plain Bootstrap? What is the desired bahaviour, i.e. do you want the tab change to be recorded in history (and thus be reachable through the browser's back button)?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I am using plain bootstrap and i do not want record of tab history

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos they are just interfering with routing with their hashes

Comment: It *may* be possible to correct this, simply by *omitting* the `href="#xxx"` attribute from the links in the tabs. (That is what angular-ui-bootstrap does).

Answer (score 0):

you could use data-target attribute instead of href for your bootstrap tab element .